# IIS Angular Page Unable to load assets folder/pages

Tags: angular, iis

I have an angular app that I have built using `ng build --prod` and deployed to IIS. I am using an assets folder where I have bunch of css and json file. Eveything works fine with I do `ng serve` but after I deploy to IIS, I get error on console as

```
main.6ff3ed8b10bf7be315c3.js:1 ERROR e {headers: t, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:8090/assets/i18n/US/en.json", ok: false, …}
```

[image]

I can navigate to the folder and do see en.json file.

[image]

but when I click the json I get eror page: [image]

What am I missing here? I do have Static Content enabled under IIS settings.
Any ideas /pointers? Thanks all.

Comment: Ensure you have `.json` extension mapped to `application/json` mime type available for your website in IIS.

Comment: Thanks. I see that its missing. Let me add and try again

Comment: that worked! @Mohsin Mehmood Would you mind posting this as answer, I will accept and close it out. Thanks.

Comment: I have posted the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you have `.json` extension mapped to `application/json` mime type available for your website in IIS

[image]